# Web Analytics Connector Parameter String Issue

Tags: marketing-cloud, community, google-analytics, email-tracking, web-analytics-connector

Please Help me

This is my parameter String

```
cm_ven=ExactTarget&cm_cat=%%EmailName_%%&cm_pla=%%ListName%%&cm_ite=%%LinkName%%&cm_lm=%%EmailAddr_%%&cm_ainfo=%%AdditionalInfo_%%&%%__AdditionalEmailAttribute1%%&%%__AdditionalEmailAttribute2%%&%%__AdditionalEmailAttribute3%%&%%__AdditionalEmailAttribute4%%&%%__AdditionalEmailAttribute5%%
```

I want to know how i can use this in my Email template and Landing pages...
Like All these will be included automatically to every link that we use in Email template and Landing page or we have to concat it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is the values located in Parameter manager for you account this will automatically be added to every link sent in an EMAIL, it does not affect landing pages/cloud pages

These are not utm strings that should be used with google anayltics

I would recommend at the least to change it to:

```
utm_source=Exacttarget​&utm_medium=Email​&utm_campaign=%%emailname_%%​&utm_content=%%linkname%%​&sfmc_j=%%jobid%%​&sfmc_s=%%SubscriberID%%​&sfmc_l=%%ListID%%​&sfmc_jb=%%_JobSubscriberBatchID%%​&sfmc_mid=%%MemberID%%​&sfmc_u=%%JobURLID%%
```

Additional Reference: [Web Analytics Connector](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_wa_web_analytics_connector.htm&type=5)

> Use the connector to tag links in your emails by automatically including specific variables in the target URLs. The analytics tool then tracks those URLs back to the email. For example, include the campaign ID in the target URL of your links to identify the web traffic generated by that campaign. When a subscriber clicks a link to your website from your Marketing Cloud email, your web analytics service tracks the activity.

Comment: ok..
Thank you for reply
Correct me if i am wrong.
As soon as i add this String over Parameter manager

utm_source=Exacttarget​&utm_medium=Email​&utm_campaign=%%emailname_%%​&utm_content=%%linkname%%​&sfmc_j=%%jobid%%​&sfmc_s=%%SubscriberID%%​&sfmc_l=%%ListID%%​&sfmc_jb=%%_JobSubscriberBatchID%%​&sfmc_mid=%%MemberID%%​&sfmc_u=%%JobURLID%%

then if i am send any Email it will be added automatically to each link and if i want to see tracking results i can check in Google analytics

One last thing for landing page links it will do the same behavior or not?

Comment: @MayankGupta Links to CloudPages from your emails are wrapped with these parameters. The pages themselves don't have an "EmailName" or any other email specific property like that. You can add the UTM tags manually to the links in your landing page or your can populate them with AMPScript from the click through from an email onto the page. You use AMPScript to get hold of the UTM parameters passed to the page from WAC by inspecting query string parameters when the subscriber lands on the page... SET @utm_medium=QUERYPARAMETER('utm_medium') and then use that variable in your links in the page

Comment: Thank you @Macca.. You are awesome.
One last thing
Can you provide me an example or usecase like where "__AdditionalEmailAttribute" tags i can use.. In Salesforce doc it is not clear

Comment: You need to ask Support to provision additional email attributes and they appear as inputs when you configure your email's properties in the UI, @MayankGupta. You typically use them to collect manual input from users to incorporate into your UTM tags. When requesting these from Support, you can ask to have between 1 and 5 of them show up in the UI and you can ask for them to be labeled with friendly names for users.

Comment: @Macca With the latest release you can self service this feature in parameter manager. When you enable it, it turns on additional email attributes also

Comment: True. Thanks @EazyE. Haven't had to play with the self serve, yet. Nice, though.

Comment: So you are saying.. If i want to include any extra email(like my agent email for my catalog page). So  i can use this parameter so that it will show analytics with that email right?

Answer (score 0):

If those are the parameter strings present in your parameter management it will be automatically added to all your email link and it will be added to cloud pages.

But you would need to provide the values for each email for those additional attributes alone.
To provide the values for additonal attributes go to Email > Email Properties > You can 
see

- __AdditionalEmailAttribute1
- __AdditionalEmailAttribute2
- __AdditionalEmailAttribute3
- __AdditionalEmailAttribute4
- __AdditionalEmailAttribute5

Provide the values according to your Analytics team for each email.

For all other attributes SFMC will automatically added. To see the values please refer [Personalization String](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_available_personalization_strings.htm&type=5).

If you don't want to add additional attributes for each email then you can follow @EazyE answer.

Comment: ok..

Thank you for this information. I appreciate it

Can you provide me an example or usecase like where "__AdditionalEmailAttribute" tags i can use..

In Salesforce doc it is not clear

Comment: @MayankGupta - use cases varies from product to product. For example, you can add a friendly name to each additional attribute for each email like category of email (newsletter, recurring) etc. which will help analytics team to identify/segment how the customer have landed into website.

Comment: So you are saying.. If i want to include any extra email(like my agent email for my catalog page). So  i can use this parameter so that it will show analytics with that email right?

Comment: That's correct it will show.

Comment: Thank you so much
One last thing can we use google analytics  as well for tracking with Marketing Cloud instead of google analytics 360?